# How to add ellipsis to text and show full text on button click?

Tags: html, css

I have a div which can be h2, p, ul depending on user content. I need to hide the text on phones so that 5 rows are visible, add three dots and show the entire test when the button is clicked. How can i do this?
Now I have it implemented using line-clamp, but this solution does not work on IOS. I also tried different solutions, but there you need to write white-space: nowrap, which does not suit me, because the text should look like on the screenshot: [image]

```js
// show/hide text
const showTextButton = document.querySelectorAll(".read-more");
const textContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".colonnes-texte");
if (showTextButton) {
  showTextButton.forEach((textButton, textButtonIndex) => {
    textButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      textContainer.forEach((container, containerIndex) => {
        if (textButtonIndex == containerIndex) {
          container.classList.toggle("show-text");
          if (container.classList.contains("show-text")) {
            textButton.textContent = "Masquer le texte";
          } else {
            textButton.textContent = "Lire la suite";
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.texte {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.show-text .texte {
  -webkit-line-clamp: initial;
}

.colonnes-texte {
    max-width: 503px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="colonnes-texte">
  <div class="texte">
    <p>Spécialiste du polycarbonate depuis plus de vingt ans, JPemball commercialise deux types de produits :</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Des cabines insonorisées, qui peuvent s’adapter à différents usages : cabines de traduction, studio d’enregistrement, cabinets d’audioprothésistes, cabines de bureau adaptées aux open-space. Des institutions prestigieuses comme le Parlement Européen
        nous font confiance pour les équiper.</li>
      <li>Des flight case ultra légers, qui permettent de transporter en toute sécurité les matériaux les plus fragiles. Nous fabriquons nos caisses de transport sur-mesure à la demande de nos clients.</li>
      <li>Nous proposons également des caisses de transport traditionnelles en bois.</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Vous souhaitez en savoir plus ?</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="read-more" type="button">Lire la suite</button>
```